# I want to learn more about OSGi and how it works, any idea where to start?

Tags: java, osgi, modularity, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I've wanted to study about modular application development, OSGi and the modularity of Java 9 in specific. But I can't seem to figure out where to start. All tutorials I find look like they are outdated or they don't provide all the information I need especially for OSGi. Are there any good books or pdf's at disposal? Or maybe some information to be shared here. All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Questions like these are off-topic on SO. Please get familiar with the rules.

Answer (score 2):

Start practicing development in OSGi.
For this you will need,

**OSGi Implementation**

- [Apache felix](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-examples-and-presentations/apache-felix-osgi-tutorial.html)
- Eclipse equinox

**Development tools**

- [Bndtools](http://bndtools.org/tutorial.html) to create OSGi compliant jars
- [Maven bundle plugin](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) if you like maven
- [Apache Servicemix](http://servicemix.apache.org/docs/7.x/quickstart/index.html) as Osgi container

Osgi is very simple. It provides guidelines on creating manifest.mf . The main thing that osgi does differently is classloading and around this only you will face issues initially.
First read about Servicemix, play around it on your machine, learn its commands. Then create a simple osgi compliant jar aka. bundle and deploy it in servicemix.

Learn about different APIs that apache felix that comes by default in servicemix. That's it. You have learnt OSGi.

If time permits, learn about [Apache camel](http://camel.apache.org) that makes integration easy between systems.

Comment: Thanks! I'm writing a study about how OSGi differs from the upcoming modular system of Java 9 and how modularity exactly works. If you got any leads or tips or tricks on the subjects, they are much welcome. Thanks again for replying.

Answer (score 2):

I have a set of [tutorials based on Apache Karaf](http://liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/Karaf+Tutorials). They are a good starting point to learn.

If you like bndtools then [Enroute](http://enroute.osgi.org/) has lots of tutorials.

There are also great tutorials at Vogella like [OSGi Modularity - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/OSGi/article.html).

Comment: Thanks for answerring! I will have a look into your tutorials. The Enroute one I followed on the OSGi site itself, I found it little helpfull since it didn't really stress the modularity in the tutorials in my opninion. I will take a look at the Vogella tutorial too. Thanks man!